# Можно ли в Visual Studio препроцессором получить параметры компилятора или линковщика?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, препроцессор

например

```
#ifdef GLEW_STATIC
УСТАНОВИТЬ ПАРАМЕТР /MT
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32s.lib")
#else
УСТАНОВИТЬ ПАРАМЕТР /MD
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: Частично да: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0084kay.aspx

Comment: Эти вещи нужно делать на уровне файлов проекта, а не в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию такой возможности нет. Но вам ничего не мешает предопределить нужный специальный макрос с помощью опции компилятора `/D`.